# Category for only one CPT

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have created CPT and added a taxonomy category.
The problem is that those categories from CPT appear also in my blog.
I would like to have diffrent categories in my blog and diffrent in my CPT portfolio.

Here is my current code
    add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
    function create_post_type() {

```
    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'label' => 'portfolio',
                'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'portfolio' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag'),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' )
        )
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Taxonomies),

> "Even if you register a taxonomy while creating the post type, you
>   must still explicitly register and define the taxonomy using
>   [register_taxonomy()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Basically, you're creating a new taxonomy called category for your Portfolio CPT. This will function exclusive of the default category taxonomy of the Posts.